# RewriteRule does not match if there is no /

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The following `RewriteRule` will match:

```
http://example/test/article/1
```

and also

```
http://example/test/article/
```

**But** not this:

`http://example/test/article` (if there is missing slash in the end of the URL)

If there is no ending `/` after `article` then I get the **Internal Server Error**.

**Rule:**

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/article/ $1-article.php?id=$2 [NC,L]
```

**How** can I change the above RewriteRule to match even if there is no slash after `article`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/article/? $1-article.php?id=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Even if in this rule `$2` is empty ... This is because your basic rule is not correct

Comment: Thanks. Ideally the url should have some id after the slash (eg. article2), so $2 should get that id, right? if there will be no id then it can display some error or redirect.

Comment: In this case, use: `RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/article(?:/(.*)/?)?$ $1-article.php?id=$2 [NC,L]`